# How can I sort and display groups when using dsquery in powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, dsquery

I am using this line of code in powershell and it works but it displays too much. I am trying to find and display where the group that contains "Avecto" in the name.

`dsquery user -samid MyUSerName| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid`

Is there anyway to add that on this script statement?

Comment: Any reason why you are using dsquery - dsget for this vs the built-in ADDS group membership cmdlets (Get-ADGroupMember, Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership, GetAuser -memberof) for this effort? Just curious. You get these by installing the MS RSAT tool, or using implicit remoting to an DC to proxy the cmdlets to your session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `where` keyword in PS (shorthanded here as `?`)

```
dsquery user -samid MyUSerName| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid | ? {$_ -match 'avecto'}
```

So it would read  where each item in the pipeline matches the string 'Avecto'

You could store the data into a variable and manipulate further, as just a simple Object array will be returned if more than one result, otherwise in a single result it will just be a string

Comment: Actually `where` and `?` are both aliases for the `Where-Object` cmdlet.

Comment: This worked. thank you :). I had the syntax with the bracket messed up.

Comment: @Del no problem. Would you mind marking it at the answer please?

Comment: I do have an additional question. How would I error check this MyUserName is null?

Comment: You could do something like:

`$myUserName = 'yourusernamehere'; $userTest = dsquery user -samid $myUserName; $matchString = 'avecto';
if($userTest -ne $null)
{
$userGroups = @(dsquery user -samid MyUSerName| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid | ? {$_ -match $matchString}); if($userGroups.Count -gt 0){ $userGroups} else { Write-Output "User $myUserName is valid, but does not belong to any groups matching string $matchString" }
}`